# how to change priority in ILIKE

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have this simple table and user records.

I just want to get users with ilike or something else to get better order in PostgreSQL 10.12.

```
CREATE TABLE users(
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY      NOT NULL,
   username           CHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO users (id, username) VALUES(1,'mandela');
INSERT INTO users (id, username) VALUES(2,'delpiero');
INSERT INTO users (id, username) VALUES(3, 'gondela');
INSERT INTO users (id, username) VALUES(4, 'del');
INSERT INTO users (id, username) VALUES(5, 'dell');
INSERT INTO users (id, username) VALUES(6, 'andel');
```

When I query "del" I want to get "del" user whose id is 4 in first place. it's ok with ordering by length. But still it is not what I want. The order should be like this. Second order must be "dell", third order must be "delpiero", fourth "andel", fifth "gondela" and sixth "mandela".

```
select * from users where username ilike '%del%' order by length(users.username) asc;
```

[Here is SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bc805/2)

Comment: you can have a look at text search ranking https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-RANKING

Comment: I will check. How can we apply it for this ? Do you have an answer ?

Comment: The chapter and examples should give you a start and see if it helps you, your question seems familiar and this can be used to weight up text search results. Else you have to write your own.

Comment: The crucial question: Why (based on what logic) should 'gondela' come before 'mandela'? Alphabet?

Comment: @nbk: Full text search is great for searching (stemmed) words or prefix or phrase matching. But it seems like the wrong tool for the given example.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter that ui why it isn't a anser. Also we don't know which order the result should have, so the answer are quite premature

Comment: [Don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: Actually we cannot say alphabet. for example delpiero should come first from andel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would seem to me, that you want leading matches first, then shortest strings first, and finally alphabetic sort order:

```
SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  username ILIKE '%del%'
ORDER  BY username NOT ILIKE 'del%'  -- leading match first
        , length(username)           -- shorter words first
        , username;                  -- finally alphabetical
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fc9456ff94b46a5744c8b9311c61eb55)*

`NOT ILIKE 'del%'` because `false` sorts before `true`. See:

- [Sorting null values after all others, except special](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21892611/939860)

Aside: Never use `char(n)`. See:

- [Any downsides of using data type “text” for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334221/939860)

Comment: That's really smart. This is really cool answer rather than using ranks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
select * from users where username ilike '%del%' 
   order by strpos(lower(users.username),'del') asc, length(users.username);
```

But on what basis is tie between "gondela" and "mandela" broken?